# preg_replace on multiple entities

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

Refer to this [link](http://classifiedads4free.com/web-it-and-computing/2124/seeking-senior-full-stack-php-developer)

I'm using the below code:

```
$ad['ad_story'] = preg_replace('/<link_me>(.*)<\/link_me>/', '<a rel="nofollow" href="http://$1">http://$1</a>', strip_tags($ad['ad_story'],"<br /><br><link_me></link_me>"),1);
```

But i do not understand why the whole chunk is being replace instead of 2 different separate links.

Am i missing something. Help definitely appreciated

Comment: Just `.*` -> `.*?`

Comment: Can you add a sample?